# Riak and this transport is not available (no protobuf) error

Tags: python, riak

I a using riak 1.2 on ubuntu , the lastest version and the lastest version of the riak python api from git hub.

when I run this code I get the below error.

```
import riak
client riak.RiakClient(host='riak.hk.myserver.com',port=8087,transport_class=riak.transports.pbc.RiakPbcTransport)
```

I can telnet in the server on port 8087. So...how do I resolve?

```
client = riak.RiakClient(host='riak.hk.myserver.com',port=8087,transport_class=riak.transports.pbc.RiakPbcTransport)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/riak/client.py", line 78, in __init__
    **transport_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/riak/transports/pbc.py", line 168, in __init__
    raise RiakError("this transport is not available (no protobuf)")
riak.RiakError
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `riak_pb` module.

```
git clone https://github.com/basho/riak_pb.git
cd riak_pb
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: This requirement should be put on the documentation of riak-python-client at http://basho.github.com/riak-python-client/tutorial.html